# Direct link to obtain a google custom search API key?

Tags: google-search-api

I have an API key that I use for Google custom search queries on the json search API that's here:

https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/services/search/web?v=1.0&rsz=8&q=

I need to send clients to a URL where they can each obtain a custom API key for their domains. However, I don't recall the URL I used to get my API key.

Does anyone know the most straight forward URL to send them to in order to obtain a key?

This one looks perfect: http://code.google.com/apis/loader/signup.html

But I'm not sure if that's the correct place for google custom search, since it refers to "Google Loader", which I'm not familiar with.

Comment: I changed the tag from app engine to search api.  this question doesn't seem to have anything to do with google app engine.

Answer (score 12):

You can get an API key by visiting https://code.google.com/apis/console and clicking "API Access". You will then need to switch on the custom search API on the "Services" tab.

Answer (score 2):

Wilfred's link got me started, but I didn't see the same thing as Wilfred. I had to click "Google APIs" (which links to here: https://console.developers.google.com/apis), then "Credentials".

"Custom Search API" is also available on the "Google APIs" screen if you need more information.