# 403 Forbidden - get url from images search from google

Tags: asp.net, http-status-code-403

Seeking pictures of my website with the google search engine get the following link:

http://www.rionegro.com.ar/diario/funciones/binario/imagen.aspx%3Fidart%3D380098%26idcat%3D9862%26idcon%3D1087449%26resolucion%3D1%26tipo%3D2?

As you can see , the url has special characters , but I think it should not be the problem.

In search result instead of displaying the image, it displays the following error:

403 Forbidden

I checking the firebug of firefox , I get the following:

```
Response Headers
HTTP/1.1 403 Forbidden
Content- Length: 0
Server : Microsoft-IIS/7.5
X -Powered -By : ASP.NET
Date: Fri, 21 February 2014 20:53:02 GMT
```

Request headers
    GET     /diario/funciones/binario/imagen.aspx%3Fidart%3D380098%26idcat%3D9862%26idcon%3D1087449%26resolucion%3D1%26tipo%3D2 HTTP/1.1
    Host: www.rionegro.com.ar
    User -Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64 ; rv: 27.0 ) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/27.0
    Accept : text / html, application / xhtml + xml, application / xml; q = 0.9 , * / * , q = 0.8
    Accept- Language: en -ar , is , q = 0.8 , en- us ; q = 0.5, in , q = 0.3
    Accept- Encoding : gzip , deflate
    Cookie: __ utma = 194708910.1295956645.1392158205.1392994869.1393012210.13 ;  __utmz=194708910.1392413045.7.2.utmcsr=200.32.2.69|utmccn= (referral)|utmcmd=referral|utmcct=/diario/inicio.aspx; _cb_ls = 1; _chartbeat2 =  qdoy9rkh40fmppme.1392162975510.1392982793966.11011111011 ; _chartbeat_uuniq = 2
   Connection: keep -alive
   Cache- Control: max -age = 0

If I put in the search the right url with special characters :

http://www.rionegro.com.ar/diario/funciones/binario/imagen.aspx?idart=380098&idcat=9862&idcon=1087449&resolucion=1&tipo=2?

The search result is correct, brings the image .

Someone can help me to solve the problem because google returns me the url above mentioned at the beginning of the text.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Batch searching on google : 403 error](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21887272/batch-searching-on-google-403-error)

Answer (score 0):

Have you [read the documentation](http://www.rfc-editor.org/info/rfc2616)? [RFC 2616](http://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2616.pdf), *Hypertext Transfer Protocol -- HTTP/1.1* says, has this to say in [§10.4.4;](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html) regarding HTTP status 403 Forbidden:

> **10.4.4 403 Forbidden**
>
> The server understood the request, but is refusing to fulfill it. Authorization will not
>   help and the request SHOULD NOT be repeated. If the request method was not HEAD and the
>   server wishes to make public why the request has not been fulfilled, it SHOULD describe
>   the reason for the refusal in the entity.  If the server does not wish to make this
>   information available to the client, the status code 404 (Not Found) can be used instead.

Almost certainly Google has detected your scraping of their search results and is denying your request.

You'll need to obtain an API key from them ([for which see this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7489862/direct-link-to-obtain-a-google-custom-search-api-key))

See also

- [Why does Google Search return HTTP Error 403?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/600536/why-does-google-search-return-http-error-403)
- [Batch searching on google : 403 error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21887272/batch-searching-on-google-403-error)

Answer (score 0):

> If your request exceeds your available quota, the server will return
>   an HTTP 403 status. See below link

[Google Places Photo Api](https://developers.google.com/places/web-service/photos)